# derivative of a power

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

By definition we have to

$$(a^{n})_{+}^{'} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{(a+h)^n-a^n}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{a^n+na^{n-1}h+...+h^{n-1}-a^n}{h} $$ $$= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} na^{n-1}+ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^{n-2}h+...+h^{n-1} $$

I would like to realize this limit precisely using the limit definition. So what I have to prove is that

$$|\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^{n-2}h+...+h^{n-1}| < \epsilon $$

Then I need to know what conditions h must meet for that limit to be verified.

Comment: Since $a$ and $n$ are fixed, if you decrease $h$ sufficiently then all the terms of the sum will be very small since each term is a fixed constant (depending on $a$ and $n$) times a power of $h$.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. My doubt would be how I would have to limit that h so that it is small enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we use the triangle inequality.
$$
\left|\sum_{i=2}^n {n \choose i} a^{n-i}h^{i-1} \right| 
\leq \sum_{i=2}^n \left|{n\choose i} a^{n-i}h^{i-1}\right|
= \sum_{i=2}^n {n\choose i} |a|^{n-i}h^{i-1}
= h \sum_{i=2}^n {n\choose i} |a|^{n-i}h^{i-2}
$$
Then choose $\delta = \min(1, \frac\varepsilon{\sum_{i=2}^n {n\choose i} |a|^{n-i}})$. Then we can write:
$$
h < \delta \Rightarrow h \sum_{i=2}^n {n\choose i} |a|^{n-i}h^{i-2}
< \frac\varepsilon{\sum_{i=2}^n {n\choose i} |a|^{n-i}} \cdot \sum_{i=2}^n {n\choose i} |a|^{n-i} = \varepsilon
$$
Some things to notice about this solution:

- The triangle inequality step is important to ensure we work with $|a|$ rather than $a$, which could be negative and cause more trouble with inequalities.
- The value $\delta$ can be very small when $a$ itself is large.
- This approach is primarily made possible by the fact of being able to factor out one $h$ and get an upper bound for the other factor.
- The above solution does not cover the case $a=0$ (which would cause a division by 0). For that case your expression becomes $|h^{n-1}|$ and we can choose $\delta = h^{\frac1{n-1}}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that this solution has a problem. In the line where it says  h < \delta

Comment: @user123456789 can you say also what the problem is?

Comment: What it does is substitute delta for its value and multiply both sides of the inequality by the same term. But it wouldn't be correct, would it? It would be missing h^i-2 right?

Comment: @user123456789 No, it's because I combined two steps in the same result. Notice that $h < \delta$ means also that $h < 1$ from the definition of $\delta$. So for the sum I use that to make $h^{i-2}$ disappear.

Comment: Okay, I already understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The limit equation you are trying to prove is that $$\lim_{h\to0}\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}a^{n-m}h^{m-1}=na^{n-1}.$$ Using the definition of a limit for a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},$ you want to prove that for all $\epsilon\gt0,$ there exists some $\delta\gt0,$ such that $|h|\lt\delta$ implies $$\left|\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}a^{n-m}h^{m-1}-na^{n-1}\right|=\left|\sum_{m=2}^n\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}a^{n-m}h^{m-1}\right|=|h|\left|\sum_{m=2}^n\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}a^{n-m}h^{m-2}\right|\lt\epsilon.$$ Using the triagle inequality, $$\left|\sum_{m=2}^n\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}a^{n-m}h^{m-2}\right|\leq\sum_{m=2}^n\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}|a|^{n-m}|h|^{m-2}\lt\sum_{m=2}^n\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}|a|^{n-m}\delta^{m-2}.$$ So all that remains is to prove that for all $\epsilon\gt0,$ there exists some $\delta\gt0$ such that $$\sum_{m=2}^n\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}|a|^{n-m}\delta^{m-2}=\epsilon.$$ This reduces the problem to one of algebra.